# Worklight push Notifications in Banking Environment

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, push, environment, banking

I am implementing push notifications for mobile banking application using GCM. According to IBM Document we have to open ports 5228,5229,5230 and 443. And our firewall should allow all the IP ranges specified in ASN15169 specification. Because of security reasons Security team not giving access to IP ranges of ASN15169. Please suggest me if we have any other way to access gcm services for application instead of allowing all the ip blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Google.

If your banking environment does not allow these ports then you need to either convince the security managers of the bank to allow it. Or, create a separate network from the banking systems where you will install a server and connect a device to test the notifications.

Comment: Hi Idan, Thanks for your reply. Our security team is okay to open the ports but they don't allow the access of IP ranges specified in ASN15169 Specification. Because it contains thousand of ip addresses. Do we have any alternative to access GCM.